# MagicalRecord updating entity in async

Tags: objective-c, magicalrecord

I'd like to update entity in async.
But, `NSLog` outputs `success - 0, error - (null)`

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
        UserData *data = [UserData MR_findFirstWithPredicate:predicate];
        data.name = name;
    } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"success - %d, error - %@", success, error);
    }];
```

How do I fix it to make updating success?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the value in localContext, after which it will be saved

```
UserData *data = [UserData MR_findFirstWithPredicate:predicate];

[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    UserData *localData = [data MR_inContext:localContext];
    localData.name = name;
} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"success - %d, error - %@", success, error);
}];
```

That's because `saveWithBlock:` saves changes only made in localContext